# Удаление повторного div'а по имени класса

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Есть два `<div>` одинакового класса. На странице один выше другого.
Как при помощи JS удалить один из них (верхний)?

```html
<div class="someclass">.....</div>
<div id="1">.......</div>
<div id="2">.....</div>
<div class="someclass">.....</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклики! Интересно, какой из вариантов будет быстрее? Первый, как я понимаю, тоже формирует массив из элементов класса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так $('.someclass:first').remove();

Answer (score 1):

- Получить массив всех элементы с таким классом ([`document.getElementsByClassName('имякласса')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName))
- Вызывать метод [`.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) у первого элементе массива
- Вот [хорошая статья по этой теме](https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document)

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('someclass')[0].remove()
```

```html
<div class="someclass">someclass #1</div>
<div id="1">обычный #1</div>
<div id="2">обычный #2</div>
<div class="someclass">someclass #2</div>
```